# Java: Converting from octal to binary without using pre-written routines

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method to convert octal numbers to binary in Java without using any pre-written routines. However, I seem to be stuck. I've been throwing my head against the wall for two days now and just can't seem to figure it out. We haven't covered arrays yet, so a lot of the answers I've been able to find online I don't understand and wouldn't be able to use anyways. If anyone could point me in the write direction with this, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

My code:

```
public static String getBinaryNumber(int octalInput) {
        int remainder;
        String binValue = "";
        do {
            remainder = (octalInput / 2) % 2;
            binValue += remainder;
            octalInput /= 2;
        } while (octalInput != 0);
        return binValue;
```

}

Earlier, I was trying to convert the octalInput to a string, take each digit one-by-one, and convert it but I was getting astronomically large numbers. I honestly don't know where to go from here, if anybody would be willing to guide me in my approach I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: But `octal` is a **string** representation of a number. If you are passed an`int` than it should be the number you are looking for.

Comment: Use a decompiler and see how Integer.toBinaryString works, it may help you to find out

Comment: @FranciscoHernandez Why a decompiler? Java is open-source, just open the Integer.java file and read the method implementation

Comment: @BackSlash you are right!! I suggested a more complicated way, open source rules, thxs

Comment: @BackSlash How could I do this?

Comment: @user3397166 You can either search the file in your machine (I don't know where it is) or go to some site like DocJar: [java.lang.Integer](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to answer the title of your question *Converting from octal to binary without using pre-written routines*:

```
public int octalToBinary(String octal) {
    int binary = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < octal.length(); i++) {
        char octalDigit = octal.charAt(i);
        int octalDigitValue = octalDigit - '0';
        // Octal must be 0 - 7
        if (0 <= octalDigitValue && octalDigitValue <= 7) {
            binary = binary << 3 + octalDigitValue;
        } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid octal number " + octal);
        }
    }
    return binary;
}
```

This uses `length` and `charAt`. I suspect this is acceptable. `getBytes` would be a reasonable substitute.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I'm not sure I'm following you. What does this line do: binary = binary << 3 + octalDigitValue; ?

Comment: @user3397166 - It shifts the current binary value left three bits and then adds in the new 3 bits of octal number.